# How to get text using vue.js 2?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have :

```
<span class="badge" id="total">10</span>
```

If I using jquery :

```
$('#total').text()
```

How to get it if using vue.js 2?

Comment: If you don't want to use jQuery, you can use javascript : document.getElementById('total'); or document.querySelector("#total"); If you want to use Vue.js you can use <span class="badge">{{ total }}</span> and put total in data or computed properties

Comment: With any library using virtual DOM you will not want to read/write directly to the DOM. If this is just the read operation, go ahead with what @SLYcee suggested. Instead if you will want to change that value, making it into an state is the right way to do it. So that you just change the state and everything happends automatically!

Comment: These should be answers, not comments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why does your HTML look like that?

You should never need to do what you're asking in a Vue application. With a MVVM application you'd have something like:

```
new Vue({
  data: {
    total: 10,
  },
})
```

Then a template like:

```
<span class="badge" id="total">{{ total }}</span>
```

That way, in your VM, when you set `this.total = 12` the DOM will update automatically and `this.total` will always return your total.